# Where to buy <whatever>? Is this low quality?

Tags: discussion

[Example 1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23753/where-to-buy-me-domain).
[Example 2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12881/alternative-to-godaddy).

Do we consider these acceptable questions here? Or are these low quality? They come up often enough, and are reported often enough, that clarification is needed so we can have a definitive answer to refer to when dealing with them going forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this low quality?

Definitely - these questions exist only to poll and the "best" answer is necessarily a popularity contest (how many people have had a good experience with XYZ provider versus ABC provider versus a bad experience with XYZ/ABC).

I think we need meta questions/answers which describe *how to shop* - though the process (research, compare, then buy) is the same for any product or service, the particulars (where can I find a list of domain providers? hosting providers? etc) do change, so we'll probably end up with a handful of meta questions - in the case of domains, it'd be good to isolate the [list of registrar lists](http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/accredited-list.html), for example.

Comment: +1 They fail the same basic test as in my similar question about CMS inquiries: not enough detail or requirements *beyond* the obvious basics(ie [IPV6](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23785/registrar-with-good-security-dns-hosting-and-dnssec-and-ipv6-resolvers)) to explain why the answer isn't "Just use one of the examples you already provided yourself."

Comment: These questions should definitely be closed.  I think the only time they are acceptable is when the user is looking for something that is exceptionally rare or possibly in specific cases like the current desire by many web masters to move away from GoDaddy very quickly, due to their support of SOPA/PIPA.  However, the question asked about GoDaddy from above did not clearly state that.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those questions are covered by [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

They could both be asked better by asking "what sort of services should I look for in a registrar when selecting between them" or some such, rather than just "What's a good registrar for x".

As [danlefree](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/628/60) states, the way these questions are currently worded they are polls at best, and are also (which is the bigger concern) often of limited long term benefit as the registrar's change their policies, or offerings, etc.